# Convert sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr to pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I'm using the SampleConsensusModelLine, which requires a pointcloud on the form of pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ::Ptr. However, the callback for the point cloud uses the form sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr. How do I convert one to the other?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234130/convert-sensor_msgs::pointcloud2constptr-to-pcl::pointcloud%3Cpcl::pointxyz%3E::ptr/) by [erwhelewoli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26166/erwhelewoli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To convert PCLPointCloud2::Ptr to PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ , you have to use the function "fromPCLPointCloud2".

For example :

```
pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloud_filtered (new pcl::PCLPointCloud2 ());
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_filtered1 (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>()); 
    
pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(*(cloud_filtered), *(cloud_filtered1));
```

---

Originally posted by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) with karma: 429 on 2016-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0